# Set custom chipDrawable background to Chip

Tags: android-chips

I want to set custom drawable background to Chip, just like that                     **chip.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_cutom_drawable));**

But it is not working.It gives an error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Do not set the background resource; Chip manages its own background drawable.
```

---

It required a **chipDrawable**. How to create chipDrawable for same. I tried but not able to find out solution. 
Please suggest me it would be appreciate.

Comment: Not sure if that's your case, but there are `chipStrokeColor` and `chipStrokeWidth` attributes to set up stroke, then you can use color resource instead of drawable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want change background color, you can try:

```
ChipDrawable chipDrawable = (ChipDrawable)chip.getChipDrawable();
chipDrawable.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Using this code you can generate multicolor chip.**

---

add this code in oncreate() or anywhere in function

```
// "i" is integer value and it will be unique for every chip. In my case I have put in chip in FOR loop that why "i" is there

Chip chip = (Chip) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item_content_lang_chip, null);
                chip.setText(contentLangModels.get(i).getContentDisplay());
                chip.setId(i);
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(buildColorStateList(getActivity(),"#1e61d5","#2e2e37"));


chipGrpContentType.addView(chip);
```

---

> Add below function in your activity

```
 public ColorStateList buildColorStateList(Context context, String pressedColorAttr, String defaultColorAttr){
        int pressedColor = Color.parseColor(pressedColorAttr);
        int defaultColor = Color.parseColor(defaultColorAttr);

        return new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                        new int[]{} // this should be empty to make default color as we want
                }, new int[]{
                pressedColor,
                defaultColor
        }
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, for whatever reason `Chip.setBackgroundColor()` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `android:background` attribute. It will be ignored because Chip manages its own background Drawable 
[chip document](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip)

Comment: Hey, ya that i know, it manages its own drawable. i want to know the same how would i create **chipDrawable** ?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using a material chip inside a dialog and getting a crash with same above error then you need to remove background attribute for your dialog set from styles.